# Is there any default transpiler and bundler used by node package manager?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm new to reactJs. I'm using node package manager (NPM) for release, build and hosting process. I first ran `npm install -g create-react-app` command to install the command whose template helped me in creating a basic reactJs application. Now my `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

If you closely look at both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` section you will not be able to find anything like Babel (a transpiler) or webpack (a bundler). So I'm wondering that when I run my website using `npn run start` command then how my reactJs class files are getting transpiled and bundled. Is there any default transpiler and bundler used by NPM or I'm missing something in my observation?

**[Update After Nicholas's comment]**:
On a contrary, in a live project code base in which I work in my office, I see that these dependencies like `babel-core`, `babel-cli`, `webpack` etc are mentioned in `devDependencies` section. They are absent from `dependencies` section. If `react-scripts` already have an implicit dependency on `babel-core`, `babel-cli`, `webpack` etc then why do they have to be mentioned explicitly in `devDependencies` section? Even `devDependencies` can also simply do so by mentioning `react-scripts` they way it is happening in my test project. Isn't it? But my fellow developers aren't doing so.

Comment: In a live project code base in which I work in my office, I see that these dependencies like `babel-core`, `babel-cli`, `webpack` etc are mentioned in `devDependencies` section. They are absent from `dependencies` section. If `react-scripts` already have an implicit dependency on `babel-core`, `babel-cli`, `webpack` etc then why do they have to be mentioned explicitly in `devDependencies` section? Even `devDependencies` can also simply do so by mentioning `react-scripts` they way it is happening in my test project. Isn't it? But my fellow developers aren't doing so.

Comment: Maybe your colleagues need to make explicit use of those modules in other parts of the project? They might have their own reasons - Why not ask them and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-scripts`, which get's called when you run `$ npm start` has those transpilers/bundlers as **it's own dependencies**.

You won't see the dependencies of an explicitly installed module, `react-scripts` in your example, within your `package.json`. They would exist as dependencies in `react-scripts` module's `package.json` instead.

For example, have a look at the [package.json of this subfolder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/package.json), of that `react-scripts` module.

It contains a bunch of dependencies, some of them being Babel and Webpack.

Comment: ohh. nice! Your git hub link for `create-react-app` solved the mystery. It precisely has all the dependencies required to build and start a reactJs app.

Comment: I finally got more insight on dependencies by using `npm run eject` command. It brings the dependencies of all the explicitly installed modules into your current project's `package.json` file. You can check the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43797225/465053).