# How to change the default configuration files used in bootstrapping of reactJs through npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I've created a very basic hello world reactJs application using `create-react-app` command which is part of npm. Here is the directory structure which I get as part of the application template:

[image]

My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I observe that every time I perform `npm run build` command it uses `index.html` present in `public` directory and `index.js` present in `src` directory to create the final production build in `build` directory. I'm sure this is happening because of all the internal plumbing happening through npm. Can someone help me understand how this is happening and how can I change these targeted files to my own custom files named `HelloWorld.html` (present in `public` directory) and `myApp.js` (present in `src` directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the build configuration you can run `npm run eject` which will remove the build dependency from your project and will add configuration files to your project, allowing you to change them as you need.

- Note that this operation is a one way ticket, you can't go back!

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Comment: Awesome! I can see this operation creates a `config`directory which contains `paths.js`. In `path.js` file, I changed the `appHtml` key in module.exports statement to `appHtml: resolveApp('public/Helloworld.html')` to load my own html file `HelloWorld.html`. Super straight-forward. You might want to add this info in  your post to make your answer more complete.